# Handling exit without saving in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, exit, qdialog

Im a student programmer using Qt to build and application for work and I am having some difficulty figuring out how to handle when a user has exited a Dialog without saving changes. The dialog is primarily purposed for data entry so being able to identify if changes have been made and then offering the user the option to save before quitting would be extremely usefull. I looked through [Qt's Documentation on QDialog](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#accept) and didn't find anything in regards to the mode that is returned if the exit button is pressed. Having a means to just identify when the exit button is clicked is first priority. Also, being a student programmer I am also open to any ideas for best practices in regards to how I should compare before and after data. The data is entered into a table so I am guessing that I would have to make something like this

```
connect(some kinda exit handler, SIGNAL(clicked), this, SLOT(comparePreAndPostTable)

QVector<QString> prechanges =  everything from the table
QVector<QString> postchanges = everything from table when exit is clicked


if(prechanges != postchanges)
{
     Give oppertunity to save
}
```

Any assistance is appreciated! It would really be nice if Qt already had something for this!

Comment: In addition to what talnicolas said, I recommend experimenting with `QWidget::setWindowModified()` and `QWidget::isWindowModified()`. You could set the property to true whenever the user does something to the document, and in the close method, check if it's true. This can also put that handy asterisk (at least in Windows) in the title bar so that the user can see if the document has been edited or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to override the `closeEvent()` method of [QWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#closeEvent) to handle the exit button of your dialog. The documentation even give an example that strangely looks like what you are looking for:

```
 void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
 {
     if (maybeSave()) {
         writeSettings();
         event->accept();
     } else {
         event->ignore();
     }
 }
```

where `maybeSave()` would compare to see if anything has changed.